# How to make my android device remember my paired TV in You Tube?

Tags: nexus-7, youtube, smart-tv

I successfully paired my android device with my TV, but unfortunately after turning down the TV, the association is forgotten. It is a nice feature to have them paired, but it is really  annoying to have to reenter the pairing number every time. Is it possible to make this pairing permanent?

I'm pairing the YouTube app in my Sony blu-ray player with my Nexus 7 android device.

Comment: This happens me all the time, through several updates of the Youtube app. I think it's just a 'feature'.